# Is a sequence of two Wagner-Meerwein rearrangements possible?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stability, carbocation

We've just studied about the Wagner-Meerwein rearrangement in carbocations.
Our teacher told us that it occurs in order to stabilize the carbocation intermediate.

Knowing the carbocation stability order,

> $\mathrm{Tertiary > Secondary > Primary} > \ce{CH3+}$

I decided to test the "limits" of this particular rearrangement reaction.

---

I drew a primary carbocation (**A**):

[image]

Upon subjecting it to a Wagner-Meerwein hydrogen-shift (in my head), I obtained the secondary carbocation (**B**):

[image]

Which was all fine and dandy; well within what I've been taught.

But seeing the potential for additional stability another Wagner-Meerwein rearrangement could provide, I conducted a Wagner-Meerwein alky(methyl)-shift and ended up with the following tertiary carbocation (**C**):

[image]

I started with a primary carbocation, changed it to a secondary carbocation and finally ended up with a tertiary carbocation.

---

Now I showed this to my teacher, but he said that in **this particular case** the carbocation (**B**) won't convert to carbocation (**C**); i.e- carbocation (**A**) isn't going to undergo *two* Wagner-Meerwein rearrangements (1,2-anionotropic shifts), because in effect it'd be a 1,**3**-shift and not the 1,**2**-shift as the Wagner-Meerwein rearrangement calls for.

A few days later, I took a different sheet with carbocations (**B**) drawn on it and carried out a Wagner Meerwein alkyl(methyl)-shift to obtain carbocation (**C**) just as before [except that this time around, my starting molecule was **B** not **A**]. I showed this to my teacher again, but the rearrangement I carried out in **this case** doesn't seem to perturb him at all. His argument is that, since my starting intermediate is carbocation (**B**), to reach carbocation (**C**), it undergoes only *one* Wagner-Meerwein rearrangement which is perfectly fine, unlike my first case which involved *two* rearrangements.

---

Now my question is, if he's right, then how would carbocation (**B**) *"know"* whether it *already* underwent a Wagner-Meerwein rearrangement [from carbocation (**A**)] before considering rearranging itself to become the more stable, carbocation (**C**)? How does it *"know"* if it's the starting intermediate or not.

Comment: Carbocations are reactive intermediates. They usually get snapped up by some other nucleophile around it. Essentially they do not have so much time to migrate so many hydrogens/alkyl groups to find what is the most stable form. However, if you do have the correct conditions, multiple alkyl shifts are indeed possible. A famous example being the [synthesis of adamantane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adamantane#History_and_synthesis) (the one with the AlCl3 step goes via a series of cationic rearrangements).

Comment: possible duplicate http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/27835/can-hydride-shift-and-methyl-shift-happen-one-after-another-in-a-carbocation/

Comment: AHHH. Why do people keep proposing primary carbocations?! This is just not plausible under normal reaction conditions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no reason why a sequence of two Wagner-Meerwein rearrangements wouldn’t happen — assuming low concentrations and thus the absence of directly capturing nucleophiles. In fact, a professor of mine once said:

> The only secondary carbenium ion is the prop-2-yl ion; all others will rearrange to form tertiary carbenium ions.

(He did explicitly exclude carbenium ions stabilised by other means from that discussion; of course an oxocarbenium ion is well-known as is an allyl cation.)

A very well-known example of this is the biosynthesis of lanosterol, in which the enzyme [lanosterol synthase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanosterol_synthase) takes squalene-epoxide, orders it in a boat-chair-boat conformation, catalyses a domino sequence of carbocations being captured by double bonds, followed by a sequence of **four** Wagner-Meerwein rearrangements and finally deprotonation to generate the backbone ring-structure of chloresterols. See the following scheme.

[image: enzymatic lanosterol synthesis]

If nature can do it, it will happen in the lab at least to a minute extent.