# What are the basic conditions for a carbocation to rearrange into a stable carbocation?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

While rearranging,every rearrangement has to increase the stability of carbocation, other than this is there any other thing that we have to keep in mind while rearrangements?

Is there any limit to the number of rearrangement to the carbocation given in the first step?

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/27835/can-hydride-shift-and-methyl-shift-happen-one-after-another-in-a-carbocation https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/59010/is-a-sequence-of-two-wagner-meerwein-rearrangements-possible

Comment: This seems too broad. Also not "every" rearrangement has to give lower energy intermediate.